# Using FCKEditor across domains

Tags: javascript, dns, fckeditor, xss, cookieless

I have a site where I'm moving all its components over to a cookieless domain. i.e. my site is example.org.uk and the cookieless domain is examplestatic.me.uk.

I am using FCKEditor as a part of this site, but it doesn't load properly when I set the source to examplestatic.me.uk/fckeditor/fckeditor.js.

How can I get FCKEditor to work on an alternate domain?

(Yes, I know this is technically XSS)

Comment: How are you including it on the page? You should have no problems including it on the page as a <script /> tag.

Comment: I do, because it's being included from an external domain.

Comment: There's absolutely no limitation against including <script /> tags from alternate domains.  This should work correctly in all major browsers.  Cross-Site Scripting applies only when a JavaScript function dynamically (e.g., via AJAX) tries to read content from another domain.  So, as long as you're including a traditional <script /> tag, you shouldn't have any trouble.  If you still are, what is the specific behavior?

Comment: The problem is more specific to fckeditor than the script tags... fckeditor uses an iframe to http://examplestatic.me.uk/fckeditor/fckeditor.html to draw its UI, then will sporadically fail because the two iframes can't communicate with each other.   At my company we solve this by setting the document.domain on the parent document (i.e. if we have www.foo.com and static.foo.com, set document.domain = "foo.com").  This won't work in your given example, as ".uk" would be considered too vague by most browsers.